# Is there any way in JQuery to change part of an image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, canvas

if i have an image (jpg, png, gif  .doesn't really matter ) and i want to have some javascript code change part of an image.

for example, lets say [i have this picture of a cookie like here](http://jokesprank.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/cartoon_cookie_biscuit.jpg).

and i have a color picker that lets a person select a color.  I want to change the color of part of the image (in this case, lets say the color of the chocolate chips) to the color that is picked.

is that possible to do in javascript / jquery ?

Comment: Not without html5. I believe the only way to get access to contents of an image client-side is to interact with it in a <canvas>.

Comment: You could likely do something with PNG files overlaid on top of each other via absolute or relative positioning.  For example, the cookie is one PNG that is mostly opaque - except for some "holes" for the chips that are translucent that reveal the darker brown background behind it.  Then if the user picks "darker chocolate chips", you just change the background color to black.  Or the cookie is all opaque and the "chocolote chips" are seperate images positioned on top.

Comment: @selbie - do you know how i would "extract" out the chips into a seperate image or layer using photoshop, etc?

Comment: Possibly take one copy of the image and "erase" all pixels that are 
"chips" to have an alpha of 0.  Then if needed, make another copy of the original and "erase" all non-chip pixels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its possible with Javascript and the `canvas` element by directly manipulating the pixel data. The below example turns blue into red.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/KDZUs/5/)**

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    image = document.getElementById("testImage");

canvas.height = canvas.width = 45;
ctx.drawImage(image,0,0);

var imgd = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 45, 45),
    pix = imgd.data;

for (var i = 0, n = pix.length; i <n; i += 4) {
    if(pix[i + 2] > 20){ // Blue threshold
        // Swap red and blue component values.

        var redVal = pix[i]; // Copy the current red component value
        pix[i] = pix[i + 2]; // Assign the current blue component value to red
        pix[i+2] = redVal; // Assign the old red value to blue.
    }
}

ctx.putImageData(imgd, 0, 0);
```

Its not very fast to do it this way however, and for larger images you would see a noticeable performance drop depending on the browser. AS for jQuery, there is nothing related to this that jQuery provides that would help.

Comment: That's greate example to use i need help from. In jquery i have detect mouth can you help how can i change the color o teeth. i susscessfully get the all pixels of mouth .how can i change the color just teeth.